# PHP: Shortcut for making multidimensional array

Tags: php, arrays

I need to do this:

```
$array['level1']['level2']['level3'] = 'someval';
```

However, I don't know how many levels there are going to be. I want to be able to create these arrays with any number of levels automatically. I am trying to adapt the following so that it forms an actual PHP array:

```
for($i=1;$i<=3;$i++){
  $string .= '_level'.$i;
};
${'array'.$string} = 'someval';

var_dump($array_level1_level2_level3); //Outputs: string(7) "someval"
```

Obviously that is no replacement for an array. I'm simply looking for a parallel that can be applied to multidimensional arrays. I suspect the answer lies in some kind of recursive function, but I'm not quite sure what.

### Update

Here is what I really want to do. I've had trouble sufficiently explaining my problems and as a result the question was closed. So, I tried to take it apart into pieces.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8002490/creating-multidimensional-arrays-in-php

Comment: Is there a reason why you need to do this?

Comment: So rather than type 49 characters, you want to type 85? If this is the case, can I interest you in some very nice real estate on the moon? Seriously though, I can't see what you want to do other than make your code confusing to anyone who needs to support it after you're done with it.

Comment: Are you sure you're solving the right problem?  Maybe arrays are the wrong medium for the data you're trying to work with....

Comment: Another thing you need to consider is unsetting an element in the array. You may not need to do it at the moment but consider `unset($array['level1']['level2']);`. With an array, it's easy. With your system, you will need to check all your variables looking for `level2` in the correct position and unset that one. Complicated code, confusing, slower.

Comment: @DaveWilsonLAMP Let me clarify: I do NOT want to use the example code I gave. I was demonstrating the type of automation I would like to have in creating the multidimensional arrays. Arrays are indeed easy. That's why I'm looking for help creating them.

Comment: Sorry but your question was not particularly clear on what you actually wanted. So you're saying that you want to create `$array['level1']['level2']...['levelN']='xyz';` via code rather than a single command. In that case, we need more information than your question gives. Where is the data coming from? Where are the index names coming from? Does it need to be stored in a multi-dimensional array like you have shown? What have you tried so far? etc.

Comment: I looked at the question which got closed down and there is no easy way to do what you want. To be honest, just thinking about it is making my brain hurt. I think you need to re-assess how you retrieve your data in the first place and go from there. Either way, I wish you luck and lots of it

Answer (score 0):

You may try the following:

```
function makeArray($array, $lowElement, $highElement, $value) {
    if($highElement == $lowElement) {
        $array['level' . $highElement] = $value;
    }
    else {
        $array['level' . $lowElement] = makeArray($array, $lowElement+1, $highElement, $value);
    }

    return $array;
}

$array = array();
$array = makeArray($array, 1, 5, 'someval');
print_r($array);   // Output: Array ( [level1] => Array ( [level2] => Array ( [level3] => Array ( [level4] => Array ( [level5] => someval ) ) ) ) )
```

Output indicates that now you have the following:

`$array['level1']['level2']['level3']['level4']['level5'] = 'someval';`